# Borel set approximation

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure on a space $X$.

From regularity of $\mu$, every Borel set can be approximated from above by an open set.

Can we approximate every Borel set from below by an open set (not a closed set).

Any idea or comment .....

Comment: It's too much to ask for open sets. But see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41462/sigma-algebra-of-well-approximated-borel-sets

Comment: @MPW Thanks for this link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Simply consider the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and the set $$B := (\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1].$$ It is widely known that $\lambda(B)=1$. On the other hand, we cannot find any open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $U \subseteq B$. Hence,

$$\sup\{\lambda(U); U \, \text{open}, U \subseteq B\} = 0.$$

Comment: Nice example, thanks.